# WCF - How to configure Site-level web.config and make all services use a same behaviorConfiguration

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0, wcf-configuration

I have a site that host more then 60 services.

With the simplified version of the wcf configuration, i dont have to speficy all the services and its corresponding endpoints.

The question is how do I speficy the service host to use the same behaviorConfiguration for all servies endpoint ?

I don't want to list all the endpoints in the web.config and speficy the behaviorConfiguration on each of them. I want all of the wcf services hosted on that virtual directory to use the same behaviorConfiguration. Any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I just need to remove the name for my endpointBehaviors

From this :

> ```
> <behaviors>
>   ...
>   <endpointBehaviors>
>     <behavior name="MyCustomBehavior">
>       <myCustomExt/>
>     </behavior>
>   </endpointBehaviors>
>   ...
> </behaviors>
> ```

To this :

> ```
> <behaviors>
>   ...
>   <endpointBehaviors>
>     <behavior>
>       <myCustomExt/>
>     </behavior>
>   </endpointBehaviors>
>   ...
> </behaviors>
> ```

See here for more details [Setting Configuration Defaults with Nameless Elements in WCF 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2009/06/26/setting-configuration-defaults-with-nameless-elements.aspx)